# Why can't I use Record.all.destroy in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently beginning to learn Ruby and the Ruby on Rails framework. I've found that in the table `records`, I can find a record with an id of 5 and delete it by using the following code:

`Record.find(5).destroy`

This makes sense- I chain methods to find the record and destroy it. However, if I want to destroy all the records in the table, the logical command would be the following, as the `all` selector selects all the records in the table:

`Record.all.destroy`

And this returns a NoMethodError! I am aware that I can use `Record.destroy_all` or `Record.delete_all` to accomplish this task, however, I'd like to know why I can't just use the most logical choice instead of having to look up things like `delete_all`. I am new to this framework, so it's entirely possible that I'm missing something fundamental here.

Thanks for any answers in advance.

Comment: indeed a good question, because I tried the same thing first... You could use `Record.all.each { |r| r.destroy }` of course, but that's not as logical as the `Record.all.destroy`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It was a design decision. DataMapper took [your approach](http://datamapper.org/docs/create_and_destroy). Being forced to write `destroy_all` explicitly can be tedious but will also prevent you from doing something you really don't want (i.e. delete everything in a table, like `x = User; ...; x.destroy`).

Comment: Thanks- this was the answer I'm looking for. I guess it might be good protection against unintended mass-deletions of records.

Answer (score 3):

I agree it would be *logical* to be able to do this. Technically speaking, `Record.all` returns a collection (or proxy to a collection) which doesn't implement the `destroy` method.

Answer (score 1):

When you have

```
Record.find(5)
```

this returns a Record object/instance that represents the data in a row in your table. Then you call the #destroy method on that object which is defined by your Record model.

When you have

```
Record.all
```

this returns an Array object. In order for you to then call #destroy on the array, you would have to monkey patch Ruby's core Array class to have a #destroy method.

Comment: yes and no... Because of ruby's dynamic nature, rails itself *could* insert a destroy action on arrays of records, without monkey patching all array objects... but it's a design decision not to, I think think.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way to avoid `Record.destroy_all` would be `Record.all.each {|r| r.destroy}`. This may somewhat satisfy your API design preferences, but should be much slower than the first option.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can (in a way). Since `.all` returns an array, and not an active record relation, what exactly would you be deleting? I wouldn't say Record.all.destroy is logical at all -- are you deleting the array object?

One thing you could do is map the resulting array, and since `map` accepts a proc(`&`), you can execute that proc for each object in your array.

```
Record.all.map(&:destroy)
```

Note, this is going to trigger callbacks on all of your objects, which might be slower than you intended. If you wanted to avoid triggering callbacks you could map the appropriate destructive method instead of destroy. (hint: :delete)

Alternately, you could just do:

```
Record.destroy_all or Record.delete_all
```

as you stated in your question.